SummarizeColumns() and AddMissingItems() May not be used in this context
I am stuck with a Power BI question. I have a report that uses a directquery connection to my source. I have created a DAX measure to calculate a Total loss:
Total loss=
Summarizecolumns(
    ‘Customer’ \[customer name\]
    ,’region’ \[country name\]
    ,’item’ \[department name\]
    ,”volumeLoss”, \[Volume Loss\]
)

Volume Loss is another measure that uses an if statement to identify, row-by-row, if there is a loss. I get the result I want in my card visual in the report. In the report I also make use of the same columns that are mentioned in the measure as slicers. When filtering, everything works fine. Only when I filter on the slicer that has both a region + country together, it fails and provides an error.
I have tried to also put ‘region’ [region name] inside the measure but it keeps on faling and I don’t understand why.
Can someone please help me?
I have tried to also put ‘region’ [region name] inside the measure but it keeps on faling and I don’t understand why.
If I only select the region name, it works without a problem. But if I go one level down in the slicer hierarchy, it throws the error. I have also tried to split up the two values of region and put them in 2 different slicers. Then I am able to select a country name, but when I then select a region name of vice versa, it throws the error again. I understand summarizecolumns had difficulties with allowing row context, but i read it was fixed as of June 2024. I am working with Power BI version of June 2024.
I also tried with:
Addcolumns(
    Summarize(
    …
    ),
“VolumeLoss”,\[VolumeLoss\]
)

but that only gives me blank values.

Can you share some data ?

pls provide some sample data and expected output.

What error message are you getting also? - edit, I see it's in the title!
